# Why I can't re-open my browser(object)?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, process, wmi

I want to create a script that open a Internet Explorer Browser with some restrictions. The script verify the `iexplorer.exe` process is running if not (means the Browser is closed) it reopen it automatically after 10 sec.

This is the script:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Const REOPEN_AFTER =10000


objExplorer.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
objExplorer.Visible = true
objExplorer.ToolBar = false
objExplorer.MenuBar = false
objExplorer.StatusBar = false
objExplorer.AddressBar = true
objExplorer.Width = 1280
objExplorer.Height = 1024
objExplorer.Left = 0
objExplorer.Top = 0
objExplorer.Resizable = false

Do While True
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
    If colProcesses.Count = False Then
        objExplorer.Navigate "http://www.google.com" 
        objExplorer.Visible = true

    End If
    Wscript.Sleep REOPEN_AFTER
Loop
```

If I started the script it runs it open the Browser but if i closed it it doesn't reopen it.

But if i run it like this then it works:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Const REOPEN_AFTER =10000


objExplorer.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
objExplorer.Visible = true
objExplorer.ToolBar = false
objExplorer.MenuBar = false
objExplorer.StatusBar = false
objExplorer.AddressBar = true
objExplorer.Width = 1280
objExplorer.Height = 1024
objExplorer.Left = 0
objExplorer.Top = 0
objExplorer.Resizable = false

Do While True
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
    If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
        objShell.Run "iexplorer.exe"
    End If
    Wscript.Sleep REOPEN_AFTER
Loop
```

Can somebody see where the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you close the browser, `objExplorer` is invalidated and when you try

```vb
If colProcesses.Count = False Then
    objExplorer.Navigate "http://www.google.com" 
    objExplorer.Visible = true
End If
```

it will fail because it doesn't point to an open browser anymore - I think you just need to create a new instance of IE at this point, eg:

```
function createExplorer

    Set createExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    createExplorer.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
    createExplorer.Visible = true
    createExplorer.ToolBar = false
    createExplorer.MenuBar = false
    createExplorer.StatusBar = false
    createExplorer.AddressBar = true
    createExplorer.Width = 1280
    createExplorer.Height = 1024
    createExplorer.Left = 0
    createExplorer.Top = 0
    createExplorer.Resizable = false

end function



Do While True
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
    If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
        Set objExplorer = createExplorer()
    End If
    Wscript.Sleep REOPEN_AFTER
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the object instantiation inside the `if colProcesses.Count=0 Then`

When the navigator is closed, the object reference stored in the variable is invalid. You need a new instance.